# Is there a metric separable space with the following properties...?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, selection-principles

Let $\omega_1<\mathfrak{q}_0$ where $\mathfrak{q}_0:=\min\{|Y|:Y\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $Y$ is not a $Q$-space$\}$.

Is there a metric separable space $X$ with the following properties:

1. $|X|\geq\mathfrak{q}_0$ ;
2. $|f(X)|\leq\omega_0$ or  $|f(X)|\geq\mathfrak{q}_0$  for any continuous real-valued function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$;
3. $X$ is completely imperfect.

That is, any continuous image avoids the power between the countable and $\mathfrak{q}_0$.

Comment: I'm guessing "$=\omega_0$" should be "$\leq\omega_0$" in (2), because of constant maps. Assuming $\mathfrak{q}_0 > \aleph_1$, wouldn't $[0,1]$ be an example? Maybe there's another property you want $X$ to have, but you forgot to write it? (Is $X$ supposed to be a $Q$-space?)

Comment: Will, Thanks for the comment!

Comment: If $q_0=\aleph_1$ then the answer is positive, so you only ask in the case $\aleph_1<q_0$?

Comment: By "completely imperfect" you mean that the Cantor space is not a subspace?

Comment: Totally-imperfect (completely imperfect) space is a topological space not containing a subset homeomorphic to a Cantor set.

Comment: Of course the question is interesting in general case: $\omega_0<\tau<\mathfrak{q}_0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Bernstein subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so $X$ and its complement intersect every uncountable closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and assume $f[X]$ is uncountable. By Lavrentieff's theorem there is a $G_\delta$ subset $G$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains $X$ and such that there is a continuous function $g:G\to\mathbb{R}$ that extends $f$. Then $g[G]$ is analytic and uncountable and hence has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. Then $G$ contains a copy $K$ of the Cantor set on which $g$ is injective. Then $X\cap K$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ and it follows that $f[X]$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ as well.